# Where is the security section of google analytics? "Security Issues" section

Tags: google, google-analytics

If you go to www.commercialmortgagemark.com you will see that is says it might be hacked.  I am trying to fix that problem, get my site registered, and add code for google analytics in my WordPress site.

Below is the instructions. I just cant find the security issues section?

Register and verify your site in Google’s Search Console.
Sign in to Search Console and check the "Security Issues" section to see details of sample URLs that might be hacked. Fix the security issue that allowed your website to be infected. Otherwise, your site is likely to be reinfected.
Read our resources for hacked sites for detailed information on how to fix your website.
Request a review in the Security Issues section in Search Console when your entire website is clean and secure. After we check that your site is fixed, we'll remove the "This site may be hacked" message.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the securty issues tool is done from within the search properties section that you register. For ease of use you can go to https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/security-issues which will link you directly to the security issues section of GWT however you will have to have added your website as a property already within GWT and gone through the steps to validate the site.

You don't mention if you have actually registered the site in GWT or not so basically...

1. Log into Google Webmaster Tools
2. Register your site using all possible validations including http, https (if used), www, and non www versions of your site
3. You will be given several methods of validation and you have to pick one. These include adding a meta tag to your site pages, adding a file with a special filename to the site root, adding a DNS entry to your DNS zone file. You need to choose one of these options and follow the instructions to validate the property to your GWT account.
4. Once validated it may take up to 24 hours for alerts and data to start appearing in your GWT account.
5. Once you start seeing data in GWT go to https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/security-issues to see any issues that have been flagged for your site